# Get a wrong state in react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

So I have a router like this:

```
const Routes = (props) => {
  const { store } = props;
  const { loggedIn } = props;
  const checkAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
    auth.checkAuth(nextState, replace, loggedIn);
  };
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route onEnter={checkAuth}>
            <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
            <Route path="help" component={HelpPage} />
            <Route path="help/new" component={HelpForm} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

Routes.propTypes = {
  loggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    loggedIn: state.user.loggedIn,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

Notice that I have props:
`const { loggedIn } = props;`

Now, every time I dispatch an action, I see in redux debugger that the state has changed. However after I click a link that is not allowed in checkAuth, I get fail and it redirects me back to the login page.

I put `console.log` in here:

```
const checkAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
    console.log("from checkAuth: " + loggedIn);
    auth.checkAuth(nextState, replace, loggedIn);
  };
```

but the result is false.

My question is, why the `loggedIn` in the Routes is not updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally removed my connect, since it does not feel right to be used for Router.
I also use `store.getState()` instead of using props and it works.

```
const checkAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
    const { user } = store.getState();
    auth.checkAuth(nextState, replace, user.loggedIn);
  };
```

I don't think my answer is perfect. So if someone has better answer or way, please post the answer :)